# How to scrape a website with a login alert window notification?

Tags: android, mobile, web-scraping

I am developing mobile application using Android studio, and I need to retrieve some information from a website. However, this website requires login; moreover, the login is located in alert window.

At this point, I have no idea how to approach this problem and would appreciate any solutions preferably using Java or JavaScript if possible.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

It is sufficient to set the default WebChromeClient:

```
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

Comment: How can I enter login credentials into an alert window using this? Also, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a longer form question with no definite answer without more info. But I have done something similar before. You should setup a webview, and then you will need to navigate that webview with injected javascript to click login, fill in and post the credentials. From there you can likely do 2 things: do all scraping in javascript and pass back what you need via an interface, or pass back the entire DOM and do your scraping with java. Here's a resource for [injecting javascript](https://medium.com/@filipe.batista/inject-javascript-into-webview-2b702a2a029f). Good luck!

Comment: My main issue is that login is located in alert window, so at the moment, I do not know how to login using JavaScript.

Comment: That's more of a javascript question than android, I don't know the answer.